# Authenticate SOAP Header request for webservice

Tags: java, web-services, soap, payload, soapheader

I need to authentication SOAP header and give the response accordingly in my web service. The authentication header will verify the userId and password information.

If authenticated, then SOAP body of the request will be processed, else Invalid Authentication message will be returned

Below is my controller

```
package com.ws.controller;

@Endpoint
public class MyWSEndpoint 
@Autowired(required=true)
private WSService service;
@PayloadRoot(localPart = "myWSRequest", namespace = Constants.TARGET_NAMESPACE)
public @ResponsePayload MyWSResponse getInfo(@RequestPayload MyWSRequest request) throws Exception
{
    MyWSResponse response = new MyWSResponse();
    response=service.getResponse();
    return response;
}
}
```

i'm using Spring + SOAP

Please advise if i do right or better approach to solve.

Any working samples or projects will be much appreciated

Comment: Is it the thing you're looking for?! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19140265/spring-ws-client-add-soapheader

Comment: kenny.. it is not helping me :(

Comment: which Spring version are you using?! Do you want to use Spring Security also?!

Comment: yes i want Spring Security also. any help will be appreciated