# Set Header of A Soap Request in Spring

Tags: java, xml, spring, rest, soap

I have been working on integrating a SOAP API with my Spring API. I have to add headers to my request,but i'm getting this is,

```
Could not complete request
org.springframework.ws.soap.client.SoapFaultClientException: No WS-Security header found
```

Please find my code below

```
public String createSaleOrder(Suborder suborder)
{
    SaleOrder saleorder = new SaleOrder();
    saleorder = setSaleOrderObject(suborder);
    CreateSaleOrderRequest request = new CreateSaleOrderRequest();
    request.setSaleOrder(saleorder);
    this.getWebServiceTemplate().marshalSendAndReceive(uri, request, 
            new WebServiceMessageCallback() {
                public void doWithMessage(WebServiceMessage message) throws IOException, TransformerException 
        {
                    SoapMessage soapmessage = (SoapMessage)message;                
                    SoapHeader header = soapmessage.getSoapHeader();

                    StringBuilder soapheader = new StringBuilder();
                    soapheader.append("<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:ser=\"http://wewewqdad.com/services/\">");
                    soapheader.append("<soapenv:Header>");
                    soapheader.append("<wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand=\"1\" xmlns:wsse=\"http://docs.oasis-open.asdasda-1.0.xsd\">  ");
                    soapheader.append("<wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id=\"UsernameToken-2\" xmlns:wsu=\"http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oaasdasd-dasdasd-1.0.xsd\">");
                    soapheader.append("<wsse:Username>username</wsse:Username>");
                    soapheader.append("<wsse:Password Type=\"http://docs.aseasdasd-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText\">password</wsse:Password>");
                    soapheader.append("<wsse:Nonce EncodingType=\"http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary\">VMEZT//J0bZw7HfZZyXAZQ==</wsse:Nonce>");
                    soapheader.append("<wsu:Created>2014-09-04 T1015.41.649Z</wsu:Created>");
                    soapheader.append("</wsse:UsernameToken>");
                    soapheader.append("</wsse:Security>");
                    soapheader.append("</soapenv:Header>");
                    soapheader.append("<soapenv:Body>");
                    soapheader.append("</soapenv:Body>");
                    soapheader.append("</soapenv:Envelope>");

                    StringSource HeaderSource = new StringSource(soapheader.toString());
                    Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
                    transformer.transform(HeaderSource,header.getResult());
                    }
    });
    return "Pushed";
}
```

**UPDATE**

The header is set. But the request object now contains extra tags which is not required and hence throwing errors. And also the tags like  how can we change these to

Raw soaprequest is given below :

```
 <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><SOAP-ENV:Header><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:ser="http://abc.efg.com/services/" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Header><wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/asdasdasd-1.0.xsd" soapenv:mustUnderstand="1">  <wsse:UsernameToken xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="UsernameToken-2"><wsse:Username>asdasdasd</wsse:Username><wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oaasdasda-1.0#PasswordText">adsasdasdasda</wsse:Password><wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://dasdasda004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">VMESASDASZT//asdasdasd</wsse:Nonce><wsu:Created>2014-09-04 T1015.41.649Z</wsu:Created></wsse:UsernameToken></wsse:Security></soapenv:Header></soapenv:Envelope></SOAP-ENV:Header><SOAP-ENV:Body><ns2:CreateSaleOrderRequest xmlns:ns2="http://asdasd.com/services/"><ns2:SaleOrder><ns2:DisplayOrderCode>156</ns2:DisplayOrderCode></ns2:SaleOrder></ns2:CreateSaleOrderRequest></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure what the exact solution to your problem is but in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19140265/spring-ws-client-add-soapheader a different approach to adding headers to soap requests was used that seemed to work :)

Comment: Can you suggest what im missing here.

Answer (score 1):

In your `soapHeader` you wrote more than the actual header but the whole Soap Envelope. Not sure this is expected.

Anyway, you could use a library to handle WS Security like **WSS4J** (often included in other frameworks).

Comment: Can we do the same thing using HttpClient class.