# Spring-WS SOAP add sub elements to header

Tags: java, spring, web-services, soap, spring-ws

How do i add sub elements to the SOAP header. I'm using old Spring ws 1.5.5 released in 2008/9.

```
  SoapHeader header = soapMsgResponse.getSoapHeader();
  SoapHeaderElement loggingHeader = header.addHeaderElement(new QName("https://svn.some.schema/logging.xsd", "LoggingHeader", "NS1"));
  //SoapElement businessId = loggingHeader.addAttribute(new QName(), "");
```

I don't know how the lines following the above would be like.

I want something like

```
<soap:Header>
    <NS1:LoggingHeader xmlns:NS1="https://svn.some.schema/logging.xsd">
        <NS1:BusinessId>ABCDEGED</NS1:BusinessId>
    </NS1:LoggingHeader>
</soap:Header>
```

Answer (score 1):

Found this in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4035423/add-child-elements-to-custom-soap-header-in-spring-ws)

> you can actually cast the message to a SOAPMessage which gives you
>   full access to all the SAAJ apis. From there you can build whatever
>   elements you want inside the header.

So after type casting you should be able to use something like this

```
SaajSoapMessage soapMessage = (SaajSoapMessage) message;
SoapHeaderElement messageId =  soapMessage.getSoapHeader().addHeaderElement(new QName("https://svn.some.schema/logging.xsd", "LoggingHeader", "NS1"));
messageId.setText("NS1:abcdef1234");
```